# SQL Server performing same calculations on different dates in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have two separate (basic) queries that are essentially the same except one is calculating a month to date sum and the the other is calculating a year to date sum.  Instead of having two separate tables, I would like each employee to have a month to date and year to date column next to their name.  I've tried unions and some subqueries, but I'm still having trouble.  I've looked at a lot of resources but haven't found what I can use.

```
--Query 1:
SELECT 
    A.EMPLOYEENUMBER AS 'Employee No.', 
    B.ENTITYNAME AS 'Employee Office', 
    B.NAME1 AS 'Employee Information', 
    SUM(A.NUMBEROF) AS 'Ent. Qty'
FROM prod.DAILYTIMESHEETLINE A
JOIN prod.EMPLOYEE B on A.EMPLOYEENUMBER = B.EMPLOYEENUMBER
WHERE A.THEDATE BETWEEN '2017.04.01' AND '2017.04.30'
GROUP BY A.EMPLOYEENUMBER, B.NAME1, B.ENTITYNAME
ORDER BY A.EMPLOYEENUMBER


--Query 2:
SELECT 
    A.EMPLOYEENUMBER AS 'Employee No.', 
    B.ENTITYNAME AS 'Employee Office', 
    B.NAME1 AS 'Employee Information', 
    SUM(A.NUMBEROF) AS 'Ent. Qty'
FROM prod.DAILYTIMESHEETLINE A
JOIN prod.EMPLOYEE B on A.EMPLOYEENUMBER = B.EMPLOYEENUMBER
WHERE A.THEDATE BETWEEN '2017.01.01' AND '2017.04.30'
GROUP BY A.EMPLOYEENUMBER, B.NAME1, B.ENTITYNAME
ORDER BY A.EMPLOYEENUMBER
```

Comment: Using  A and B is not a clear as would be dts and e. If you also want to group by month, you should add something like datepart(mo,thedate).

Comment: The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]` - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: This is great - thanks!  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
SELECT 
    A.EMPLOYEENUMBER AS 'Employee No.', 
    B.ENTITYNAME AS 'Employee Office', 
    B.NAME1 AS 'Employee Information',
    SUM(case when A.THEDATE BETWEEN '2017.01.01' AND '2017.04.30' then A.NUMBEROF else null end) AS 'Ent. Qty1', 
    SUM(case when A.THEDATE BETWEEN '2017.04.01' AND '2017.04.30' then A.NUMBEROF else null end) AS 'Ent. Qty2'
FROM prod.DAILYTIMESHEETLINE A
JOIN prod.EMPLOYEE B on A.EMPLOYEENUMBER = B.EMPLOYEENUMBER
WHERE A.THEDATE BETWEEN '2017.01.01' AND '2017.04.30'
GROUP BY A.EMPLOYEENUMBER, B.NAME1, B.ENTITYNAME
ORDER BY A.EMPLOYEENUMBER
```

Be carefull to where : I let BETWEEN '2017.01.01' AND '2017.04.30' because '2017.01.01' < '2017.04.01' , Modify in consequence ;)

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful.  Thank you so much!